# how to get rid of the data type label under header character, numeric ... and the total rows n: at the footer from flextable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, flextable

See the attached image for mtcars dataset.

[6 rows of mtcars data display as a flextable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEtfE.png)

I have been searching and studying for quite a while and found nobody talked about this. I believe this community will give me an answer. many thanks.

Comment: I have just found a solution as well, which uses the delete_rows from flextable. Basically, It uses delete_rows(i = 2, part = "header") to get rid of the greyed datatype labels. Similarly, for the n: footnote, delete_rows(i=1, part = "footer") does the job.

Unfortunately, it works only for rendering to html, not docx.

Comment: I believe you just need to call `flextable` and not `as_flextable()`. Also, the issue you are mentioning is fixed in the dev version

Comment: Thanks David for the update. Yes, the dev version does fixed the above issue. By the way, the table caption is still not working for me on rendering docx from quarto.

Comment: OK, BTW, I can't help without a reproducible example, you can declare "it does not work", I can't do anything because I don't know your quarto version, I don't know if you define the caption correctly with Quarto, etc

Comment: I tested it with mtcars. It could be my mistake. But it does work for HTML, but not for docx. mtcars |> head() |> 
  select(1:4) |> 
  flextable::flextable() |> 
  flextable::set_caption(caption = "This is a test") . My quarto version 1.3.433.

Comment: The documentation of `set_caption()` explain that Quarto itself manage captions, it is not possible to use another way with Quarto. https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/set_caption.html#using-quarto-. It does work the same with HTML, https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/blob/master/R/printers.R#L225